# Simple relay switching program crashes UNO

Tags: relay

A very simple

```
digitalwrite(pin, HIGH)
delay(1200)
digitalwrite(pin, LOW)
delay(1200)
```

crashes the uno after about half an hour. Of course it works again after pressing the reset button.

It's switching this [relay](http://store.cutedigi.com/relay-module-of-linker-kit-for-pcduino-arduino/)

[image: relay]

Which is connected to a 230v 80W DC motor. The relay cuts the '+'

Because I've read that 230v stuff can be too much for such a litte relay,
I've disconnected the motor and not the relay switches another 24v OMRON P2RF-05-PU (10A250VAC) relay, which has his own 24V Mean Well power supply. And connected the motor to that one.

I thought this solved my problem, but now the Arduino crashes after about 3 hours.
Any thoughts on what else I could try?

Comment: Neither of those relays are rated for 230VDC, only 230VAC. The DC rating is usually about a tenth of the AC rating. You will destroy the relay contacts, cause massive arcs, and lots and lots of EMI while it switches. Get the right relays for the job.

Comment: Apologies, should have mentioned: the motor is rated 230VAC 80W 50hz.
The AC to DC conversion is done within the motor.

Comment: You may want to brush up on switching theory WRT arcs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_suppression

Comment: Nothing to brush up, only learning new stuff for me.
From what I've read, I should try a solidstate. Going to do that tomorrow.

Comment: post the complete source. In my project I have two 30 A 230VAC relays and one 10 A 230 VAC relay and other sensors and actuators connected to Uno WiFi working all day